# ¿Como agregar una clase despues de un append con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

quisiera agregar una clase para un elemento `<tr>` con javaescript ya lo intente con `$("<tr>").addClass("nombre-clase")` pero no funciona, hay alguna manera de que orienten?

este es mi codigo en JavaScript

```
$("#tablaEmpleados tbody").append(

                $("<tr>").append(
                    $("<td>").text(empleado.nombreCompleto),
                    $("<td>").text(empleado.refDepartamento.nombre),
                    $("<td>").text(empleado.sueldo),
                    $("<td>").text(empleado.fechaContrato)
                )
            )
```

Lo quiero agregar en el `$("<tr>").append`, espero me puedan apoyar con ese detalle que no eh podido realizar.

Comment: Quizás esta pregunta te ayude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056509/jquery-addclass-to-table-tr-element-where-text-is-found

Comment: Muchas gracias, deja le echo un vistazo.

Comment: Si, tambien asi le intente y nada! pero les dejo mi respuesta para que vean como lo resolví y espero a que alguien le ayude.

Answer (score 1):

gracias al comentario de Andres Gardiol, pude resolver el problema. Les dejo la manera en como resolví por si alguien tiene el mismo conflicto, le ayude.

Lo que me ayudo fue colocar esto antes de mi `$("<tr>").append`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tablaEmpleados tbody tr').filter(function () {
                return $.trim($(this).text()).length > 0;
            }).addClass("empleado");
        });
```

En donde primero colocamos el id de la tabla a la que queremos recurrir, despues al siguiente hijo que seria el `tbody` y por ultimo al elemento que es `tr` para mi caso, y ya! Eso es todo.

Asi es como quedo:

```
$("#tablaEmpleados tbody").append(

 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tablaEmpleados tbody tr').filter(function () {
                return $.trim($(this).text()).length > 0;
            }).addClass("empleado");
        });

            $("<tr>").append(
                $("<td>").text(empleado.nombreCompleto),
                $("<td>").text(empleado.refDepartamento.nombre),
                $("<td>").text(empleado.sueldo),
                $("<td>").text(empleado.fechaContrato)
            )
        )
```